# Problem with pvclust in R

Tags: r, clustering

Hey, im a beginner to R and trying to run pvclust so as to test a cluster solution.

I've managed to load data and run the heirachical cluster, however the code i find online for running pvclust is constantly producing errors - just wondering if someone can point out where I'm going wrong...

here is my code (data already transposed. my dataset is called "transpose" below..)

```
##loaddata

transpose <- 
  read.table("C:/Users/Tim/University/Advanced Design and Data Analysis/Assignment/transposed.csv",
   header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

View(transpose)
hello <- hclust(dist(model.matrix(~-1 + 
  var001+var002+var003+var004+var005+var006+var007+var008+var009+var010+var011+var012+var013+var014+var015+var016+var017+var018+var019+var020+var021+var022+var023+var024+var025+var026+var027+var028+var029+var030+var031+var032+var033+var034+var035+var036+var037+var038+var039+var040+var041+var042+var043+var044+var045+var046+var047+var048+var049+var050+var051+var052+var053+var054+var055+var056+var057+var058+var059+var060+var061+var062+var063+var064+var065+var066+var067+var068+var069+var070+var071+var072+var073+var074+var075+var076+var077+var078+var079+var080+var081+var082+var083+var084+var085+var086+var087+var088+var089+var090+var091+var092+var093+var094+var095+var096+var097+var098+var099+var100+var101+var102+var103+var104+var105+var106+var107+var108+var109+var110+var111+var112+var113+var114+var115+var116+var117+var118+var119+var120+var121+var122+var123+var124+var125+var126+var127+var128+var129+var130+var131+var132+var133+var134+var135+var136+var137+var138+var139+var140+var141+var142+var143+var144+var145+var146+var147+var148+var149+var150+var151+var152+var153+var154+var155+var156+var157+var158+var159+var160+var161+var162+var163+var164+var165+var166+var167+var168+var169+var170+var171+var172+var173+var174+var175+var176,
   transpose)) , method= "ward")

plot(hello, main= "Cluster Dendrogram for Solution hello", xlab= 
  "Observation Number in Data Set transpose", sub="Method=ward; 
  Distance=euclidian")
```

all the above works fine, except the below where i try the pvclust

```
library(pvclust)

fit <- pvclust(transpose, method.hclust="ward",
   method.dist="euclidean")

plot(fit) 
pvrect(fit, alpha=.95)
```

the error comes back=

```
library(pvclust)
> fit <- pvclust(transpose, method.hclust="ward",
+    method.dist="euclidean")
Warning in dist(t(x), method) : NAs introduced by coercion
Error in hclust(distance, method = method.hclust) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)
> plot(fit) 
Error in plot(fit) : object 'fit' not found
> pvrect(fit, alpha=.95)
Error in nrow(x$edges) : object 'fit' not found
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer without seeing the data itself, but my best guess is that you have some non numerical entries in the matrix/dataframe (which is what is expected by `pvclust`). For example,

```
> as.numeric(c(1,2,"NA"))
[1]  1  2 NA
```

or

```
> dist(c(1,2,"NA"))
   1  2
2  1   
3 NA NA
```

will produce the same warning message ('*NAs introduced by coercion*'). I deliberately used `"NA"`, but any element that is not numerical will result in the same warning message.

So,

1. A warning message is issued when trying to compute a distance matrix from the non-numerical input
2. Then, `hclust` failed when it is called within `pvclust`. Again,

   ```
   > hclust(dist(c(1,2,"NA")))
   ```

   will throw the same error message.

In your first try, you called `hclust` by using a matrix. Can't you just check that you use the same variables in both cases, or that there is no strange values in your data (e.g., `summary(transpose)`), or no missing values coded as the character `"NA"` instead of `NA`, as below:

```
> xx <- data.frame(replicate(3, sample(c(1,2,3), 3)))
> xx[2,3] <- "NA"
> is.na(xx[2,3])
[1] FALSE
> sapply(xx, is.character)
   X1    X2    X3 
FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
> apply(xx, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
X1 X2 X3 
 0  0  0 
# Now if we had a true NA value, we would see
> xx[2,3] <- NA
> apply(xx, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
X1 X2 X3 
 0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pvclust is a bit odd in that it expects your data to be organized with the observations in the rows, rather than the columns. This is what the documentation in `?pvclust` tries to explain, just not very well.

try transposing your original data matrix in the call to `pvclust()` and see if it runs.

i.e.,

```
fit <- pvclust(t(transpose), method.hclust="ward",method.dist="euclidean")
```

as an aside its not good R practice to give names to objects that are also the names of R functions e.g., 'transpose'

Good luck

Comment: I don't think this can explain the warning or error messages reported by the OP.

Comment: @chi you could be right, its not easy to say without seeing the original data. My experience with pvclust is that it tends to throw error messages that are not very easy to interpret.

Comment: When would you ever have observations in columns?